# Data Binding Text Capitalization

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding, capitalization

I have my XML file looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="name"
            type="com.example.android.model.Name"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@{name.title + ' ' + name.first + ' ' + name.last}"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And POJO class is:

```
public class Name {

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("first")
    @Expose
    private String first;
    @SerializedName("last")
    @Expose
    private String last;
}
```

The response comes in all small letters, i.e.,

```
title = mr
first = jon
last = skeet
```

I am aware of multiple ways & stratagies to captialize from within Java files, but is there any way to capitalize **initial letter of each word** using **data binding** from **XML file itself** instead of capitalizing first letter of each word **from within corresponding Java files**?

Comment: You should fix your data instead.  Believe it or not, there are languages and names out there that don't start with capitals.  Automatically capitalizing names is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a `BindingAdapter` like this [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html):

```
@BindingAdapter({"name_text"})
public static void setName(TextView textView, Name name) {
    String string = String.valueOf((name.title).charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + name.title.substring(1)
            + " " + String.valueOf((name.first).charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + name.first.substring(1)
            + " " + String.valueOf((name.last).charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + name.last.substring(1);
    textView.setText(string);
}
```

And specify your `TextView` as:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/app_name"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:name_text="@{name}"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The TextView will be like:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/app_name"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@{String.valueOf(name.title.charAt(0)).toUpperCase()
         + name.title.substring(1) + ' '
         + String.valueOf(name.first.charAt(0)).toUpperCase()
         + name.first.substring(1) + ' '
         + String.valueOf(name.last.charAt(0)).toUpperCase()
         + name.last.substring(1)}"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>
```